# Cannot pass numerical ID in function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want make a multiply chating system like facebook. So I collect this script from this [webpage](http://qnimate.com/facebook-style-chat-box-popup-using-javascript-and-css/)

In this script they are passing 2 variable in register_popup function as id and name. Now if I pass any numerical value as id for twice or more, this script not working. But for a new numerical value work well.

So I want to sand my usersID as ID and UserNAME as NAME for further process. How can I solve this? Here is this script:

```html
<a class="content" href="#" id="Aaa" data-name="aaa">AAA</a><br>
<a class="content" href="#" id="1013" data-name="bbb">BBB</a><br>
<a class="content" href="#" id="1014" data-name="ccc">CCC</a>

<script>
    $(document).on('click', 'a.content', function() {
        var ID = $(this).attr("id");
        var NAME = $(this).data("name");
        register_popup(ID, NAME);
    });

    //this function can remove a array element.
    Array.remove = function(array, from, to) {
        var rest = array.slice((to || from) + 1 || array.length);
        array.length = from < 0 ? array.length + from : from;
        return array.push.apply(array, rest);
    };

    //this variable represents the total number of popups can be displayed according to the viewport width
    var total_popups = 0;
    //arrays of popups ids
    var popups = [];
    //this is used to close a popup
    function close_popup(id) {
        for (var iii = 0; iii < popups.length; iii++) {
            if (id == popups[iii]) {
                Array.remove(popups, iii);
                document.getElementById(id).style.display = "none";
                calculate_popups();
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    //displays the popups. Displays based on the maximum number of popups that can be displayed on the current viewport width
    function display_popups() {
        var right = 220;
        var iii = 0;
        for (iii; iii < total_popups; iii++) {
            if (popups[iii] != undefined) {
                var element = document.getElementById(popups[iii]);
                element.style.right = right + "px";
                right = right + 320;
                element.style.display = "block";
            }
        }
        for (var jjj = iii; jjj < popups.length; jjj++) {
            var element = document.getElementById(popups[jjj]);
            element.style.display = "none";
        }
    }

    //creates markup for a new popup. Adds the id to popups array.
    function register_popup(id, name) {
        for (var iii = 0; iii < popups.length; iii++) {
            //already registered. Bring it to front.
            if (id == popups[iii]) {
                Array.remove(popups, iii);
                popups.unshift(id);
                calculate_popups();
                return;
            }
        }
        var element = '<div class="popup-box chat-popup" id="' + id + '">';
        element = element + '<div class="popup-head">';
        element = element + '<div class="popup-head-left">' + name + '</div>';
        element = element + '<div class="popup-head-right"><a href="javascript:close_popup(\'' + id + '\');">&#10005;</a></div>';
        element = element + '<div style="clear: both"></div></div><div class="popup-messages"></div></div>';
        document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].innerHTML = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].innerHTML + element;

        popups.unshift(id);
        calculate_popups();
    }

    //calculate the total number of popups suitable and then populate the toatal_popups variable.
    function calculate_popups() {
        var width = window.innerWidth;
        if (width < 540) {
            total_popups = 0;
        } else {
            width = width - 200;
            //320 is width of a single popup box
            total_popups = parseInt(width / 320);
        }
        display_popups();
    }
    //recalculate when window is loaded and also when window is resized.
    window.addEventListener("resize", calculate_popups);
    window.addEventListener("load", calculate_popups);

</script>

<style>
    @media only screen and (max-width: 540px) {
        .chat-sidebar {
            display: none !important;
        }
        .chat-popup {
            display: none !important;
        }
    }

    .chat-sidebar {
        width: 200px;
        position: fixed;
        height: 100%;
        right: 0px;
        top: 0px;
        padding-top: 10px;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
        border: 1px solid rgba(29, 49, 91, .3);
    }

    .sidebar-name {
        padding-left: 10px;
        padding-right: 10px;
        margin-bottom: 4px;
        font-size: 12px;
    }

    .sidebar-name span {
        padding-left: 5px;
    }

    .sidebar-name a {
        display: block;
        height: 100%;
        text-decoration: none;
        color: inherit;
    }

    .sidebar-name:hover {
        background-color: #e1e2e5;
    }

    .sidebar-name img {
        width: 32px;
        height: 32px;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }

    .popup-box {
        display: none;
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 0px;
        right: 220px;
        height: 285px;
        background-color: rgb(237, 239, 244);
        width: 300px;
        border: 1px solid rgba(29, 49, 91, .3);
    }

    .popup-box .popup-head {
        background-color: #6d84b4;
        padding: 5px;
        color: white;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 14px;
        clear: both;
    }

    .popup-box .popup-head .popup-head-left {
        float: left;
    }

    .popup-box .popup-head .popup-head-right {
        float: right;
        opacity: 0.5;
    }

    .popup-box .popup-head .popup-head-right a {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: inherit;
    }

    .popup-box .popup-messages {
        height: 100%;
        overflow-y: scroll;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use ajax call to handle the data.

function sendData() {

```
 $.ajax({
     context:this,
     type:"POST",
     dataType:"json",
     data: { ID: userID, NAME: UserNAME },

     success: function(response){
        //something
     },
             error: function(errorData){alert(errorData);}
 });
```